# slider/carousel with auto and continuous scrolling

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a jquery plugin to slide images horizontally in a way that the scrolling is continuous (copntent is displayed in an infinite loop) and enabled by default (autoscroll). The closest I've found is jcarousel however the "auto" property can only be set to 0 (in which case autoscroll is disabled) or 1+ which represents a pause time between the slides.

Have anyone already come across what I'm looking for?

Comment: I need a slider - with swipe, pagination and should automatically slide as well? Any help ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the [Cycle](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) plugin.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed the "continuous" option allows for constant scrolling: http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/continuous.html. However this plugin only displays 1 picture at a time, whereas I'm looking for a slider which looks like jcarousel.

Comment: Sorry, this was not obvious to me from your question.

Answer (score 3):

I was kinda looking for the same thing and I found this:

http://bxslider.com/